# Why base class private attribute accessed by derived class ?

Tags: php

I don't understand this topic. Why private member's of base class are accessed by the derived class?

```
<?php
class A{
private  $name; // private variable
private $age; //private variable
}
class B extends A{
 public function Display($name,$age){
 echo $this->name=$name." age is ".$this->age=$age;
   }
}

$ob=new B();
$ob->Display("xyz",23);
?>
```

Output :
xyz age is 23

Comment: You just have to make you variable ```protected``` instead of ```private```

Answer (score 2):

The `B` class doesn't inherit the `$name` and `$age` properties, since they're private.

However, PHP will let you assign variables without declaring them as class properties first:

```
<?php
class A
{
    private $name; // private variable
    private $age; //private variable

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = "a";
    }
}
class B extends A
{
    public function display($name, $age) {
        $this->name2 = $name; // new name2 variable, NOT A's name
        $this->age2 = $age; // new age2 variable, NOT A's age
        echo $this->name2." age is ".$this->age2.PHP_EOL; 
        echo $this->name; // A's name, undefined property warning!
    }
}

$ob=new B();
$ob->display("xyz", 23);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/NJZU8)

> xyz age is 23

Notice how I use `name2` and `age2` instead of `name` and `age`, and the output is still correct. As you can see, you're not accessing `A::$name`, but `B::$name2` that was defined in `B::display()`, and trying to acces `A::$name` gives you an undefined property warning.

So, although not exactly intuitive, this is expected behavior for PHP.